# Puppeteer: Lazy images not loading in headless mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Here is my code. I am using `AdBlock` Plus Extension.

I have a task to take a screenshot for the web page(Have used lazy loading) with images in the right sidebar under the heading `PAID CONTENT` and images on the bottom under the heading `PAID CONTENT`.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  const pathToExtension = require('path').join(__dirname, 'abp_chrome');

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: [
     `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
     `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`
   ]
 });

 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await timeout(5000);
 await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 1200});
 await page.goto('https://edition.cnn.com/2015/07/31/world/mh370-debris- 
   investigation/index.html', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
 await page.evaluate(() => {
   window.getDimensions = function(element) { 
    rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
     x: rect.x,
     y: rect.y,
     width: rect.width,
     height: rect.height
  };
 };
});
await autoScroll(page);  
await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png', fullPage: true});
await browser.close();
})();

 async function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
 }

 async function autoScroll(page){
   await page.evaluate(async () => {
   await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   var totalHeight = 0;
   var distance = 100;
   var timer = setInterval(() => {
     var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
     window.scrollBy(0, distance);
     totalHeight += distance;

     if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
      clearInterval(timer);
      resolve();
     }
    }, 500);
   });
 });
}
```

I have used scrolling to load lazy images, but images are not loading as I have seen in screenshot.

Here is captured screenshot from code.
[image]
As in screenshot, there is no images tiles, Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: If the lazy loaded images are using any class based selector, you can use waitForSelector option to wait till the selectors are loaded. I have used similar strategies to screenshot pages. You may try waiting for 1 second after scrolling before taking the screenshot to see if that helps.

Comment: ads are not loading, I have used `page.waitForSelector('.OUTBRAIN', {visible: true})` I have also tried wait time for 1 second but ads are not loading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have fixed this with the help of the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/665).

I have added user agent:

```
page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
WAIT_UNTIL=load")
```

Comment: you save my life. deal with this for a day.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function autoScroll(page){
   let criteria=3; //lazy load 3 page
   for (let pageIndex = 1; pageIndex < criteria; pageIndex++) {
      await page.evaluate(async () => {
        let x = await document.querySelectorAll(
          'set lazy element selector array'
        );
        await x[x.length - 1].scrollIntoView();
        return x.length;
      });
      await page.waitFor(1000);  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2022 Answer:

The new headless option may solve this if it works in headful but not headless. From the Github discussion: "`headless: 'chrome'` is meant to be the same browser implementation as the headful mode. The old headless mode is actually a different browser underneath." Setting to `headless: 'chrome'` personally solved the issue for me

```
puppeteer.launch({
     headless: 'chrome'
})
```

[Github discussion](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5214)